# Add custom shuffle filter to Timber/Twig

Tags: php, arrays, filter, twig, timber

I want to shuffle an array and added following filter to my functions.php

```php
    add_filter( 'timber/twig', function ( $twig ) {

        $twig->addFilter( new Timber\Twig_Filter( 'shuffle', function ( $array ) {
            $shuffle = shuffle( $array );
            return $shuffle;
        } ) );

        return $twig;
    } );
```

However, following code returns nothing:

```
{% for item in ["WordPress", "React", "Craft", "NodeJS", "Laravel", "Tailwind", "Vue", "Stencil"]|shuffle %}
     <h2 class="outline">{{ item }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The parameter "array" is sent by reference to the function [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and the function itself returns `true`/`false` whether the shuffle was successful or not and not the actual shuffled array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comment from DarkBee, I got it working with the following code:

```
add_filter( 'timber/twig', function ( $twig ) {

    $twig->addFilter( new Timber\Twig_Filter( 'shuffle', function ( $array ) {
        shuffle( $array );
        $newArray = [];

        foreach ( $array as $item ) {
            array_push( $newArray, $item );
        }

        return $newArray;
    } ) );

    return $twig;
} );
```